# RxJava: How to express doOnFirst()?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, rx-android

I am using RxJava and I have an `Observable` with multiple items inside. What I would like to do is run function A on the first item, function B on all of them and function C when the `Observable` is completed:

```
-----1-----2-----3-----|-->
     |     |     |     |
     run A |     |     |
     |     |     |     |
     run B run B run B |
                       |
                       run C
```

is there a clever way of expressing this with lambda functions? I have the following solution already, but it looks ugly and I suspect that there is a better way to do this:

```java
observable.subscribe(
        new Action1<Item>() {
            boolean first = true;

            @Override
            public void call(Item item) {
                if (first) {
                    runA(item);
                    first = false;
                }
                runB(fax1);
            }
        },
        throwable -> {},
        () -> runC());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I've found an easy solution for this myself:

```js
Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.just(1, 2, 3).share();
observable.take(1).subscribe(this::runA);
observable.subscribe(
    this::runB,
    throwable -> {},
    this::runC);
```

This works single-threaded and it seems to work multi-threaded too, but I have to admit I'm not too confident about that so far.

Comment: If your original observable does not have subscription side-effects this will work just fine.

Comment: @TBieniek This is exactly the way I'd implement it. Also there seem to be some overly complicated answers on this post.

Comment: Can you guarantee that `runA` would run before `runB` for `1`?

Comment: Putting the second `.subscribe()` inside the handler for the first one should guarantee that `runA` happens first.

Answer (score 8):

Use `Observable.defer` to encapsulate per subscription state (being a boolean that indicates if we are on the first record).

Here's a runnable class that demos use:

```
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Observable.Transformer;
import rx.functions.Action1;

public class DoOnFirstMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Observable<Integer> o = 
            Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
                .compose(doOnFirst(System.out::println);
        // will print 1
        o.subscribe();
        // will print 1
        o.subscribe();
    }

    public static <T> Transformer<T, T> doOnFirst(Action1<? super T> action) {
        return o -> Observable.defer(() -> {
            final AtomicBoolean first = new AtomicBoolean(true);
            return o.doOnNext(t -> {
                if (first.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                    action.call(t);
                }
            });
        });
    }

}
```

Even though OP was asking about RxJava1, here's the same solution above but for RxJava2:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.FlowableTransformer;
import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer;

public class DoOnFirstMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Flowable<Integer> f =
                Flowable.just(1, 2, 3)
                        .compose(doOnFirst(System.out::println);
        // will print 1
        f.subscribe();
        // will print 1
        f.subscribe();
    }

    public static <T> FlowableTransformer<T, T> doOnFirst(Consumer<? super T> consumer) {
        return f -> Flowable.defer(() -> {
            final AtomicBoolean first = new AtomicBoolean(true);
            return f.doOnNext(t -> {
                if (first.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                    consumer.accept(t);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @tir38 I don't mind the addition of RxJava2 example but equivalent of Observable in RxJava2 is Flowable. Would you like to amend?

Answer (score 2):

There's `doOnNext` and `doOnTerminate` (or similar) already built in, so it sounds like all that's missing is performing an action on just the first item.  Here's one way.  You could publish your stream, then in one block the stream proceeds as normal, while in a separate subscription we listen only for the first event (with `first`) and perform the action when we receive it.  Here's an example:

```
observable.publish(new Func1<Observable<Item>, Observable<Item>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Item> call(Observable<Item> itemObservable) {
        itemObservable.first().subscribe((Item item) -> runA(item));
        return itemObservable;
    }
}).subscribe(/* some actions and subscription as usual ... */);
```

If this looks too verbose, you could put this in a utility Transformer and preserve some of the builder syntax.  e.g.:

```
public static class Transformers<T> implements Observable.Transformer<T, T> {
    private final Action1<T> action1;

    private Transformers(final Action1<T> action1) {
        this.action1 = action1;
    }
    // cover for generics
    public static <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> doOnFirst(final Action1<T> action1) {
        return new Transformers<T>(action1);
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<T> call(final Observable<T> observable) {
        return observable.publish(new Func1<Observable<T>, Observable<T>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<T> call(Observable<T> observable) {
                observable.first().subscribe(action1);
                return observable;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
observable
    .compose(Transformers.doOnFirst((Item item) -> runA(item)))
    .subscribe(/* chain and subscribe as usual... */);
```

Obviously this all looks much nicer with Lambda syntax, the above is my guess how it would look like.

Comment: using publish is a very heavyweight solution for this. I'll try and put up something simpler.

Comment: @DaveMoten do you mind elaborating why you consider it too heavyweight?  Do you mean in terms of the processing overhead that `publish` adds or in terms of syntax?

Comment: in terms of processing overhead. My solution could also be a bit more efficient if written as an Operator to save a volatile read every emission.