# RxJava2's delay(rx.functions.Func1) is not emitting items in order

Tags: delay, rx-java2

I am using this signature of `delay`:

```
public final <U> Observable<T> delay(Func1<? super T,? extends Observable<U>> itemDelay)
```

[javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#delay(rx.functions.Func1))

I am using `Func1` to return an `Observable` which acts as a sort of "trigger". My goal is to delay items until an outside async operation completes. Once that operation completes I want to emit all items that have been delayed and all future items *in order*.

Here is some sample code that shows what I'm trying to do:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.ObservableTransformer;
import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
import io.reactivex.subjects.ReplaySubject;

public class Example {

    private ReplaySubject<Object> delayTrigger = ReplaySubject.create(); // (1)

    public void main() {
        System.out.println("============ MAIN ============");
        SourceThread sourceThread = new SourceThread();
        sourceThread.start();

        sourceThread.stream
                .compose(doOnFirst(integer -> startAsyncOperation())) // (2)
                .delay(integer -> delayTrigger) // (3)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe((Integer integer)
                        -> System.out.println("onNext: " + integer));
    }

    private void startAsyncOperation() {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>> long async operation started");
        SomeOtherThread someOtherThread = new SomeOtherThread();
        someOtherThread.start();
    }

    private void onAsyncOperationComplete() {
        System.out.println("<<<<<<< long async operation completed");
        delayTrigger.onNext(new Object()); // (4)
    }

    /**
     * From https://stackoverflow.com/a/32366794
     */
    private <T> ObservableTransformer<T, T> doOnFirst(Consumer<? super T> consumer) {
        return observableTransformer -> Observable.defer(() -> {
            final AtomicBoolean first = new AtomicBoolean(true);
            return observableTransformer.doOnNext(t -> {
                if (first.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                    consumer.accept(t);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    /**
     * Some thread to simulate a some time delayed source.
     * This is not really part of the problem,
     * we just need a time delayed source on another thread
     */
    private final class SourceThread extends Thread {
        private ReplaySubject<Integer> stream = ReplaySubject.create();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                stream.onNext(i);
                System.out.println("Source emits item: " + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private final class SomeOtherThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                onAsyncOperationComplete();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At (1) I create a `ReplaySubject` that will act as my trigger, at (2) I start the async operation, at (3) I delay until the trigger emits something; finally at (4) I put something into the trigger stream when async operation completes.

This works fine for the most part, except when the async operation completes, the stream returned from `delay` is out of order.

```
I/System.out: Source emits item: 46
I/System.out: Source emits item: 47
I/System.out: <<<<<<< long async operation completed
I/System.out: Source emits item: 48
I/System.out: onNext: 0
I/System.out: onNext: 48 <---- problem here!!!
I/System.out: onNext: 1
I/System.out: onNext: 2
I/System.out: onNext: 3
```

Item 48 is emitted from `delay` before items 1 - 47. Item 49 will get emitted out of order as well. This will continue until items 1-47 are emitted, then the stream cleans up. But there is a big section of un-ordered items. Is there a way I can fix this? Am I using `delay` correctly? Is this a bug in delay?

For reference this is just a sample. In my "real" problem I have no way to re-order the emitted items once they get out of order (i.e. they aren't nicely numbered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `delay` operator has no ordering guarantees because the inner source for item #1 may signal later than another inner source for item #2 in general. Any async signal may throw off the ordering, even if coming from a source such as a terminated `ReplaySubject`.

I assume you want to prefetch the main source but not let it through before the external signal, right? In this case, you can use `concatArrayEager` where the first source's completion triggers the emission of the prefetched second source:

```
PublishSubject<Integer> delayer = PublishSubject.create();

Observable.concatArrayEager(
    delayer,
    sourceThread.stream
)

// somewhere async
delayer.onComplete();
```

Comment: I figured that the internal ordering was not preserved, but based on whenever the inner sources signaled emission. Thanks for the suggested change.